Using Thoth.Json how do I decode "{}"?
I have to interact with an api which exposes a get_status end point. If the process is "ready" it returns "{}" as a response. If it is not ready it returns a json object with all sorts of reasons why it is not ready.
I can model this with something like this
type NotReady = ...

type Status =
  |Ready
  |NotReady of NotReady


How do I implement a deserializer for this?
My attempt so far is along the lines of
module Status =
    let decoder: Decoder<Status> =
        let ready_decoder =
            Decode.string
            |> Decode.andThen (
                function
                | "{}" -> Decode.succeed Ready
                | invalid -> Decode.fail "Not ready"
            )

        let not_ready_decoder = NotReady.decoder |> Decode.map NotReady
        Decode.oneOf [ ready_decoder; not_ready_decoder ]

But this does not work. Even the following does not work:
let x = "{}" |> Decode.fromString Decode.string

It fails with
Error at: `$`
Expecting a string but instead got: {}

I can do something ugly by inspecting the plain string first then returning something but I want something more elegant that uses the features of Thoth.
EDIT
Here is one way of doing it
type NotReady = { a: int; b: string }

type Status =
    | Ready
    | NotReady of NotReady

module Status =
    let decoder: Decoder<Status> =
        Decode.map2
            (fun a_opt b_opt ->
                match a_opt, b_opt with
                | Some a, Some b -> { a = a; b = b } |> NotReady
                | _ -> Ready
            )
            (Decode.optional "a" Decode.int)
            (Decode.optional "b" Decode.string)

let ready_json = "{}"
let not_ready_json = """{"a": 1, "b": "hello"}"""
let unexpected_json = """{"b":"not suppored to happen"}"""
ready_json |> Decode.fromString Status.decoder |> printfn "ready result:%A"

not_ready_json
|> Decode.fromString Status.decoder
|> printfn "not ready result:%A"

unexpected_json
|> Decode.fromString Status.decoder
|> printfn "unexpected result:%A"

The problem is that unexpected json still decodes to Ready. Of course, the real problem is that the API owner should not be returning empty objects which have implicit meaning, but there is not much I can do about that.

"{}" is (as I'm sure you know) just an empty JSON object. This seems like a simple problem, I think your code is more complicated than it needs to be. But it would help to have a sample JSON object, I don't know if "ll sorts of reasons" means an array of strings or something else.

Lets go with {"a" : 123; "b" : "def"}. I don't think my problem is related to any specific non empty object. It is the empty object that is giving me trouble.
